# Insert text from a text box into and Access 2010 DataBase using VB.Net

Tags: database, ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

I have 3 text boxes I am using as a contact form. I am trying to use VB to take this data and add it into my database.
I have run debugging and it says the error is in the INSERT INTO string. ![Screen Grab of Debugging] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufYPs.png

Any ideas?

```
Imports System
```

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Partial Class Contact
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Name As String = txtName.Text
    Dim Email As String = tbxEmail.Text
    Dim Comment As String = tbxComment.Text

    Dim objConnection As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim objcmd As OleDbCommand = Nothing

    Dim strSql As String
    Dim dbConn As OleDbConnection = Nothing

    dbConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = Z:\Documents\Databases\user.accdb")
    dbConn.Open()

    strSql = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, comments) VALUES (?,?,?)"
    objcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSql, dbConn)
    objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@username", Name))
    objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@email", Email))
    objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@comments", Comment))
    objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


    dbConn.Close()
    Response.Write("Submitted Successfully")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USER is a reserved keyword in MS-Access, To use it as a table name your need to enclose it in square brackets

```
strSql = "INSERT INTO [user] (username, email, comments) VALUES (?,?,?)"
```

As a side note, try to use the [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) when you work with disposable objects.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Name As String = txtName.Text
    Dim Email As String = tbxEmail.Text
    Dim Comment As String = tbxComment.Text

    Using dbConn = New OleDbConnection(".......")
        dbConn.Open()
        Dim strSql = "INSERT INTO [user] (username, email, comments) VALUES (?,?,?)"
        Using objcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSql, dbConn)
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Name)
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email)
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", Comment)
            objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
    Response.Write("Submitted Successfully")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried 2 things. If I add the Using statement I end up with build errors, stating both `dbconn` and `objcmd` hide a variable in and enclosing block.

Comment: I have tried running without the 'Using statement', just adding square brackets to user `[user]`. While debugging the following error is thrown _Unhandled exception at line 940, column 13 in http://localhost:1169/ScriptResource.axd?d=DT3YJR8QaqV61-teuz0hgq5a3FQA8MHrkniUz6btQKrdAAJIBru1i4ufsCj0lnk7SbkE-BpmROGP1Po5qv6t2Vic05otOdeKe1XYXd0-lSx5dnzvvNHmrEh9dnlkqayZF065umFxuLGoU_dhd8lCxQ2&t=ffffffffda74082d

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed._

Comment: Rewritten all the answer code, all the variables for connection and command are implicitly created inside the using statement block and destroyed at the End Using, so you don't need to declare and initialize them before the block. The second error doesn't seem to be related to this question

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I realise now I hand;t amended my code to reflect the variables being declared inside the USING statement.

Comment: I should also add the javascript runtime error was caused by the update panel containing my form. I think the error was being thrown as the `response.write` was being loaded outside of the panel as I failed to add a placeholder