# How to insert multiple rows into an access database?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into an Access database. The table is named `sales` with the columns `sandwich` and `price`. The data I'm trying to insert is contained in multiple `TextBox` controls.

So far I've tried this code:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [sales] ([sandwich]) VALUES ([@sandwich])"
Try
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(constring)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
            conn.Open()
            For Each Order As TextBox In grpbill.Controls
                If Order.Text.Length > 0 Then
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sandwich", Order.Text)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
            Next Order
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

It's working fine. The program is checking for full `TextBox` controls only and inserting the correct number of rows however when I check the database the values are all the same, inserting the value of the last `TextBox` over and over.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I doubt it is working right at all with more than one textBox in the grpbox - you cannot AddWithValue over and over - if there are 3 items, it will try to add 3 parameters with the same name which if course will fail.

Comment: First I would change `grpbill.Controls` to be `grpbill.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()`. That way you know you're only ever going to deal with a `TextBox`. And you should consider adding your parameter before the `For` and then updating the value in each loop.

Comment: @Plutonix as I stated at the end of my question the program is entering the same value over and over. I wouldn't be asking if nothing was wrong :S

Comment: If you are adding parameter(s) within a loop you should also use `cmd.parameters.clear` before adding them. This will ensure you dont run into any exceptions with parameters already added.

Comment: @Bugs how do I do that?

Comment: When you `AddWithValue` for items 2, 3, 4 etc, you are **adding** a 2nd, 3rd or 4th parameter which isnt specified in the SQL.  So it only uses the first one (over and over).  Dont use `AddWithValue`; add one (**1**) parameter and just change the value in a loop.

Comment: @DaveB thank you my good sir problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the parameter *outside* the `For Each` loop and the update the value on each loop. Do away with `.AddWithValue` and use `.Add`. `.AddWithValue` has to infer the database type for your query parameter.

You should also consider using `grpbill.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()` instead of `grpbill.Controls` as this will ensure you only loop through the `TextBox` control collection and not include a `Label` or `GroupBox` or a `Panel` etc.

Note that I have the following LINQ statement:

```
From t In grpbill.OfType(Of TextBox)()
Where t.TextLength > 0
Order By t.TabIndex
```

With this you can now remove your `If` statement. Also be sure to set the `TabIndex` for each `TextBox` so that they are added to the database in the right order.

I've also removed a `Using` to shorten the code a little. You can use a comma instead. This is just personal preference.

Lastly, you don't need `conn.Close()` as the `Using` will handle all that for you.

Code:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [sales] ([sandwich]) VALUES ([@sandwich])"
Try
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(constring),
          cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@sandwich", OleDbType.VarChar)
        For Each Order As TextBox In From t In grpbill.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                                     Where t.TextLength > 0
                                     Order By t.TabIndex
                cmd.Parameters("@sandwich").Value = Order.Text
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next 
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are declaring and setting values.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Name As String = txtName.Text
    Dim Email As String = tbxEmail.Text
    Dim Comment As String = tbxComment.Text

    Using dbConn = New OleDbConnection(".......")
        dbConn.Open()
        Dim strSql = "INSERT INTO [user] (username, email, comments) VALUES (?,?,?)"
        Using objcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSql, dbConn)
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Name)
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email)
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", Comment)
            objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
    Response.Write("Submitted Successfully")
End Sub
```

[Insert text from a text box into and Access 2010 DataBase using VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375516/insert-text-from-a-text-box-into-and-access-2010-database-using-vb-net)