# VB.NET 2010 Inserting data to table in access

Tags: vb.net

PLease I need help whenever I register my form to database, it says registration successful but the last table (the TRANSACTION table) data information from my form does not input the info in my database only the table FORM and STUDENT have data from my form. Is there something wrong in my TRANSACTION code? or in database?
PLEASE HELP :((

```
        sql = "INSERT INTO FORM VALUES ('" & txtformnum.Text & "' , '" &  bcboRequest.Text & "' , '" & txtTotal.Text & "')"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con) '"
        da.Fill(ds, "FORM")
        sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES ('" & txtstudnum.Text & "','" & txtSurname.Text & "','" & txtGName.Text & "', '" & txtMName.Text & "', '" & txtAddress.Text & "', '" & status & "' , '" & txtYr.Text & "' , '" & cbostype.Text & "' , '" & chkClearance.Text & "', '" & txtCourse_Track.Text & "' , '" & txtCNumber.Text & "' , '" & dot.Value & "' , '" & dotdue.Value & "')"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "STUDENTS")
        Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO TRANSACTION (Transaction_num,Stud_num,Form_num,Total Fee)" + "VALUES (" & txttransactionno.Text & ",'" & txtstudnum.Text & "'," & txtformnum.Text & "," & txtTotal.Text & ");"
        Dim sqlcommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery)
```

Comment: Declaring a `OleDb.OleDbCommand` does not run it. You need to execute it. And your title mentions a database connection, but your question has nothing to do with a database connection.

Comment: I dont get it, why you code like this. in Writing an SQL statement or SQL Clause, it is important to have the field where you are going to insert your values. For Example: `INSERT INTO TABLE (FieldName1 , FieldName2) VALUES (TEXTBOX1.TEXT, TEXTBOX2.TEXT)` Something like this. You must designate the fieldname where you want to insert the textbox values. AND also your command does not execute the query you have created.

Comment: @AlexisVillar The INSERT statement actually works if the table is named FORM and the fields are in the exact right order to match the data. It's not a good practice but it's legal.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23375516/62576) and its answer.

Comment: You need to do some reading on ADO.NET and SQL in general.  You are trying to execute an `INSERT` statement by calling `Fill` on a data adapter.  That's ludicrous.  The `Fill` method is supposed to execute a `SELECT` statement and populate a `DataTable` with the result set.  If you want to execute an `INSERT` statement directly then you call `ExecuteNonQuery`  There are explanations and examples of that all over so anyone who has done a reasonable amount of reading on the subject knows that.

Comment: Sorry wrong title. the problem is that the two table (FORM and STUDENT) is working when inserting data from the form but the last form the TRANSACTION form does not work when inserting data even the registration is successful

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what database you're using, but if you're using MySQL or MS SQL Server then the keyword TRANSACTION is reserved and must be escaped to work within your statement.

If using MySQL, try changing your statement to `INSERT INTO "TRANSACTION"`

If using SQL Server, change your statement to `INSERT INTO [TRANSACTION]`

If you're not using either of those, post what database system you're using and I'll post the proper escape syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO TRANSACTION (Transaction_num,Stud_num,Form_num,Total Fee)" + "VALUES (" & txttransactionno.Text & ",'" & txtstudnum.Text & "'," & txtformnum.Text & "," & txtTotal.Text & ");"
```

To

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO TRANSACTION ([Transaction_num],[Stud_num],[Form_num],[Total Fee]) " + "VALUES ('" & txttransactionno.Text & "','" & txtstudnum.Text & "','" & txtformnum.Text & "','" & txtTotal.Text & "');"
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your code:

```
sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```